# Round to nearest, dynamic decimal place?

Tags: python

See the reproducible code below. Looking to round to the nearest decimal place, based on the "step" set for each in the dictionary. Desired output is given at the bottom. Can't just use `round(x, 1)` or `round(x, 2)` as the steps can be different, unless you can determine what position the 1 is in the decimal place?

```
from numpy.random import choice
from numpy import arange

# Define some ranges with steps
range_one = {"low": -2.0, "high": 2.0, "step": 0.1}
range_two = {"low": -2.0, "high": 2.0, "step": 0.01}
range_three = {"low": -2.0, "high": 2.0, "step": 0.001}

# Get the full range of values for each
a_range_one = arange(range_one['low'], range_one['high'], range_one['step'])
a_range_two = arange(range_two['low'], range_two['high'], range_two['step'])
a_range_three = arange(range_three['low'], range_three['high'], range_three['step'])

# Make a random selection from each range
random_choice_one = choice(a_range_one)
random_choice_two = choice(a_range_two)
random_choice_three = choice(a_range_three)

# See the outputs are off
print(random_choice_one)
print(random_choice_two)
print(random_choice_three)

# OUTPUT
# # Machine rounding/arange issue...
# 0.7000000000000024
# -0.22999999999999843
# -1.9890000000000012

# DESIRED OUTPUT (rounding based on the "step" for each)
# 0.7
# -0.23
# -1.989
```

Comment: What about using `-np.log10(step)` to get an approximate rounding value?

Comment: That'll work perfect! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you keep track of the step of each choice. If you know the steps are powers of 10, you can use:

```
print(round(random_choice_one, -int(log10(range_one["step"]))))
```

You probably want to wrap this into a function returning a string, like

```
def str_rounded(value: float, rng: dict) -> str:
    return str(round(random_choice_one, -int(log10(rng["step"]))))
```

which you can use as `print(str_rounded(random_choice_one, range_one))`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the job?

```
range_one = [n/10 for n in range(-20, 21)]
range_two = [n/100 for n in range(-200, 201)]
range_three = [n/1000 for n in range(-2000, 2001)]
```